# Proper way for a man to urinate while standing

Tags: sexuality, bathroom, shulchan-aruch, kedusha-holiness, mishnah-berurah

Maran HaShulḥan 'Arukh, citing the Talmud Bavli ([Niddah 13B](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_36099_24.pdf)), states that a man must avoid holding his member when urinating ([Oraḥ Ḥayim 3:14](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_1/0009_Siman_3_Seif_13b-Siman_4_Seif_1a.pdf)). That is, holding *me'atarah u'lema'alah* is forbidden while holding *me'atarah u'lemattah* is permitted (using the Gemara's terms).

[MishnaBeruraYomi.org](http://mishnaberurayomi.org/mp3_shiurim/Chelek_1/0009_Siman_3_Seif_13-17.mp3) (2:17-2:57) and [MishnaBerura.com](http://mishnaberura.com/MBerura/31.mp3) (18:30-19:25) both explain *me'atarah u'lema'alah* (the forbidden area) to be the shaft until where it connects to the glans (*'atarah*). RaSh"I explains the Gemara accordingly (s.v. מעטרה ולמעלה).

Considering that the glans (*'atarah*) contains the [highest concentration of nerve endings in the male body](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/all-about-sex/201207/so-thats-how-it-feels), how does this make sense? Would it not make more sense to permit holding a place with *fewer* nerve endings and to avoid holding a place with *more* nerve endings (to avoid stimulation)?

Comment: Perhaps it's not a din in sensitivity rather a din in how much area you could be holding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37800/discussion-between-andrewmh20-and-lee).

Comment: The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch states that one _is permitted_ to hold his organ of circumcision while urinating if he has "bread in the basket" according to the Artscroll translation.

Comment: Doesn't the Shulchan Aruch pasken that one shouldn't urinate while standing to begin with?

Comment: @Ploni http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60038/halachically-why-are-men-allowed-to-use-urinals?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

A small Google search tells me that, it is almost impossible to ejaculat only through glans stimulation,
but very possible through shaft stimulation

(There is a halacha that someone can not have children if he does not have any glans)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no medical expert, far from it, but, as far as I can tell from an online search, those extra nerve endings appear to be primarily in the foreskin.

Judaism mandates circumcision for almost all Jewish males.

Comment: @msh210 I agree that this doesn't really answer the question and rather calls its validity into question (which is fine).

Comment: @Clint TMI. Way TMI.